# Как вставить текст с активности в кнопку находящуюся в фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, у меня есть активность и в этой активности есть определенная переменная с текстом, на активности есть фрагмент состоящий из кнопки, как присвоить текст данной кнопки?

Каким образом это делается?

Answer (score 2):

```
//в Активити
Fragment f;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("text", "Your text");
f.setArguments(bundle);

//в фрагменте
String text = getArguments().getString("text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Если переменную надо прочитать более одного раза, а не единожды передать во фрагмент, то можно добавить в активити геттер и вызывать его во фрагменте.

В активити:

```
private int someValue;

public int getSomeValue() {
    return someValue;
}
```

Во фрагменте:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).getSomeValue();
```

Будьте осторожны, `getActivity()` может вернуть `null`, если вызывается слишком рано (фрагмент ещё не добавлен) или же слишком поздно (фрагмент уже убран). Кроме того, если Ваш фрагмент используется в нескольких активити, не забудьте предварительно проверить тип: `if (getActivity() instanceof YourActivity)`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вариант довольно безопасный, но несколько неуклюжий: использовать *SharedPreferences*: `putString()` & `getString()`

```
public class PreferenceService {

    private static PreferenceService mInstance;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private PreferenceService() {}

    public static PreferenceService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (ApplicationSingleton.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new PreferenceService();
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public void save(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
        e.putString(key, value);
        e.apply();
    }

    public String load(String key) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```